# Google App "search pending" notification stuck on Marshmallow

Tags: notifications, 6.0-marshmallow, google-apps, nexus

"1 search pending" notification from Google App is stuck on my Marshmallow phone since yesterday. Based on other answered questions about stuck notifications, I tried:

1. To Cancel the pending search
2. Rebooting my phone
3. Turning off and turning back on the notifications for Google App
4. Forcing the Google app to close
5. Turning off the notifications for Google App, rebooting the phone, and turning notifications back on.
6. Trying to search the same thing again

None of the above "solutions" worked.

I had applied the June 2016 security updates from Google last week. Not sure if this had something to do with it.

Any help in this regards is appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: [Google play stuck on “Waiting for network…” when installing an app on mobile data](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/151637/16575) Can you check if the answer there matches/solves your issue as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to uninstall the Google app, it would ask you if you want to replace the app with the factory version. Select yes. That should do it, worked for me. :)

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me: uninstall Google app (replace app with factory version), then go to app updates in Play Store and reinstall update for Google app. Caveat: it also reset my current widgets and app shortcuts :) Had to re-create my home screen and re-add the widgets, minor inconvenience I guess.

Comment: It can be done without downgrading the Google app or wrecking your home screen. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Toggling notification block for the Google app seemed to clear the stuck notification on my HTC One M8 running Lollipop. This should also work in Marshmallow:

- Long press on the stuck notification until it says the app name, in this case "Google App"
- Press the 'i' to open notification prefs (or go to settings > sound & notification > app notifications > Google app)
- **Switch "Block" on then off again**
- the stuck notification should be cleared

No uninstall needed. No settings lost. No home screens cleared.

Note: The question mentioned "turning off notifications for the Google app" which is unclear. There is a notification on/off setting in the Google app, but a notification block at the system level is different. Unsure if the OP tried this method, but it worked for me.

Comment: This worked to clear the notification for me temporarily, but it pops right back up after reenabling the notifications.

Answer (score 0):

first you should try to disable Google app updates, after that application manager will ask for the turning factory version you should accept that request. that solution worked with me.